# How java Handler objects are related to android Handler objects?

Tags: java, android

```
    Handler handler =new Handler();
```

This is how we create handler in android and java.

I would like to know the extra characteristics possessed by handlers in android?

Comment: _my doubt is clear to u from the question_ No it is not... post code, input and expected output + errors

Comment: no, `Handler` is not an interface, it is: `public class Handler { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[android.os.Handler:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)**

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread/message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

**[java.util.logging.Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html)**

A Handler object takes log messages from a Logger and exports them. It might for example, write them to a console or write them to a file, or send them to a network logging service, or forward them to an OS log, or whatever.

A Handler can be disabled by doing a setLevel(Level.OFF) and can be re-enabled by doing a setLevel with an appropriate level.Handler classes typically use LogManager properties to set default values for the Handler's Filter, Formatter, and Level